# Filter elements by class name and value-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my form i have many elements with class named "myClass" . i am iterating these elements using .each function.
i want to find the index of the  **last** elements which has this class name and **has value**(value not empty) ... how can i do it?

```
$(":text[name^=distanceSlab]").each(function(i){
  var Indx =  // find the index of the last element which has class name= myClass and has value
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
$(":text[name^=distanceSlab]").each(function(i, value) { 
  alert(i + ': ' + value); 
});
```

The above shows you how to get index for each element ... but I am not sure what selector you require from your question. You can just use class name as selector like this :

```
$(".myClass").each(function(i, value) { 
  alert(i + ': ' + value); 
});
```

To find the last element use [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/), like so :

```
$('.myClass').last();
```

Combine selectors to find last with a value :

```
 $('.myClass[value!=""]').last();
```

Comment: I do not understand why this got a downvote since it is answering the question perfectly. Or is it the actual index number of the element that you want? Maybe this `$('.myClass[value!=""]').length` (or -1 if you count 0-based (which is normally the case))?