# Find the next input field and set focus if it is empty- jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have form with many input fields like this,

http://jsfiddle.net/WPDF9/1/

i am trying to loop the element which has name distanceSlabCost

```
$(":text[name^=distanceSlabCost]").each(function(i){
    var curTxtBox = $(this);
     var nextTxtBox =       // find the next text field (?)
     var nextTxtFieldId      // find the id of next text field  (?)

 });
```

How to get the id of the next textField element there?
also ,there if the value of next field is empty set focus to that field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305100/filter-elements-by-class-name-and-value-jquery/7305125#7305125

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea maybe go through the container divs with class=.distance_slab and use next() to get the following container div and it's child elements(children()).

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the following code, but it should work:

```
var fields = $(":text[name^=distanceSlabCost]");

for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
    var curTxtBox = fields[i];
    var nextField = i+1 <= fields.length-1 ? fields[i+1] : null;
    var nextId = nextField ? nextField.attr("id") : null;
}
```

I hope this will help you ;)

ps: the benefit of this approach is that you have to query the dom only once!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got it right:

```
$(":text[name^=distanceSlabCost]").each(function(i){
    var curTxtBox = $(this),
        nextTxtBox = curTxtBox.next('input[type=text]'),
        nextTxtFieldId = nextTxtBox.attr('id');

    if(nextTxtBox.val() === '') {
        nextTxtBox.focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: The last Textfield does not have a next one. Check `if(nextTxtFieldId === undefined) ...`

Comment: That's not my code. And the last iteration still searches for a next Textfield that doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$(":text[name^=distanceSlabCost]").each(function(i){
    var curTxtBox = $(this);
     var nextTxtBox =  curTxtBox.next('input:text');     // find the next text field (?)
     var nextTxtFieldId = nextTxtBox.attr('id');    // find the id of next text field  (?)

 });
```

Comment: its giving nextTxtBox =undefined

Comment: You had a lot of typos in your fiddle, now it works http://jsfiddle.net/95rqY/22/ with my code

Comment: there it works! but in my code it is not .. i will put my code in fiddle

Comment: see now its giving undefined.. its my actual code   http://jsfiddle.net/95rqY/27/

Comment: That's because in your structure every input field has no siblings and so next() finds nothing. You should change your html or think of a different solution!

Comment: can u suggest different solution